# calculate what months are between two dates?

Tags: visual-foxpro

Between the dates 11/28/2023 and 10/01/2022 I know how many days there are. DATE(2023, 11, 28) - DATE(2022, 12, 02), how can I calculate that between these two dates are the months of November 2022, December 2022 to November 2023?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the year parts to 12*1 months, e.g

```
? DateMonthDiff(DATE(2022, 11, 1), DATE(2023, 12, 1))

FUNCTION DateMonthDiff(tdStart,tdEnd)
RETURN (YEAR(m.tdEnd)-YEAR(m.tdStart))*12+(MONTH(m.tdEnd)-MONTH(m.tdStart))
ENDFUNC
```

Inspired by Martina Jindrová,
http://www.foxite.com/archives/0000309490.htm

Comment: Hi Stefan, this would return 1 month between 1/31/2022 and 1/1/2023 but that might be the desired result.

Comment: Good point, Merhaba @CetinBasoz :)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean full months difference then:
(ie: 28 Dec 2022 to 27 Jan 2023 is 0 months)

```
? DateMonthDiff(DATE(2022, 11, 1), DATE(2023, 12, 1))

Procedure DateMonthDiff(tdStart, tdEnd)
    Local ix
    For ix = 1 To Ceiling((m.tdEnd-m.tdStart)/365)*12
        If Gomonth(m.tdStart, m.ix) > m.tdEnd
            Return m.ix-1
        Endif
    Endfor
    Return 0
Endproc
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for the list of months, not how many there are. If that's right, I'd use GOMONTH() to move forward one month at a time and check whether I've passed the end date.

Comment: You may be right Tamar.